# UnitOfWork pattern not using with petaPoco ORM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, orm, petapoco

I am new to PetaPoco ORM in .net and i found it quite confused when i take a look on to the business logic part, where we are not using UnitOFWork pattern along with Repository pattern . We usually use unitOfWork pattern along with Repository pattern in Entity FrameWork. Do anybody know why unitOfWork pattern not using in PetaPoco ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reffer to the petapoco documentation here -> http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/

And do a search for "transaction" you will find the clostest thing to unit of work that exists within petapoco.

Hope that helps..

Remember this is a mirco ORM so it may not have everything you are looking for.. if you want speed then other than hand coding your DAL there isnt (in my opinion) any other route to take.